# Session variables not getting unset on subdomain after unset on main domain

Tags: php, session

I have it setup so I can share session data across the main domain plus a subdomain, on the subdomain script I am using the code:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', COOKIE_DOMAIN);

session_start();
```

`COOKIE_DOMAIN` is equal to something like `.domain.com`

Sessions show up fine on the sub-domain after using this code, however when they are unset on the main domnain via code like:

```
unset($_SESSION[SESSION_PREFIX.$variable]);
```

They get unset on the main domain but not the sub-domain.

Comment: That is not “destroying a session”, that’s just unsetting certain entries within the session array. And if you have a concurrent script instance running on the subdomain, it might just be that it writes that data _back_ into your session because it is still in its $_SESSION array at that point. For us to be able to see what is _really_ going on, you will have to provide more detailed info of what you’re doing when and where.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I guess I used the wrong terminology. I will change my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to set it in your `php.ini` instead..

```
session.cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"
```

Comment: So the problem was most likely that you used `ini_set` to manipulate this setting on the subdomain _only_ – so when the session was started on the main domain, it used a different setting for the cookie domain, and therefor it was not visible to the subdomain. If you had used `ini_set` on _both_ domains from the start, that would have “fixed” it as well.

Comment: Actually I *did* try using it on both domains and it didn't work.