# Session only showing up on subdomain after restarting browser

Tags: php, session

I have it setup so I can share session data across the main domain plus a subdomain, on the subdomain script I am using the code below on the subdomain:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com');

session_start();
```

Thing is, session data that is set by the main domain is only viewable on the sub-domain *after* a browser restart.

Why is this and can it be fixed?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, [Session variables not getting unset on subdomain after unset on main domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094300/session-variables-not-getting-unset-on-subdomain-after-unset-on-main-domain)

Comment: @CBroe It's not a duplicate; just because they were solved in the same fashion doesn't mean they are duplicate questions; hence your down vote isn't justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to set it in your `php.ini` instead..

```
session.cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"
```